# Appending list works for the first iteration but after I get list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Caesar cipher shift. Whenever I go about shifting the character based on the alphabet position it gives me the "list index out of range" error.

```
password = input('type in the word you want to turn into a password: ')
shift = int(input('What do you want your caesar shift to be? '))
new_password = []

password = list(password)
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
i = 0
for num in range(0, len(password)):
    for letter in alphabet:
        i += 1
        if password[num] == letter:
            move = i
            new_password.append(alphabet[(move + shift) - 1])
            print(new_password[num])
```

I expected that this program would continue to continue to append letters to new_password based on how long the first password was. However after the first letter, I get the "list index out of range"

Comment: Your code is not working (`i` is never defined).

Comment: How about posting the rest of your code. What you have here cannot stand on its own. I suspect the problem lies with `alphabet` but we can't know for sure. 

`i`, `alphabet` and `new_password` are all uninitialized in the code you supply.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that your `move` and `shift` values end up being outside of the index values available in `alphabet`. You will need to add special cases to wrap around the indexes when `(move + shift) - 1` is greater than the length of alphabet.

Comment: That's something I didn't even think about at the moment. I appreciate that you brought it up. However I still can't get my program to run through more than one character before the "list index out of range" error occurs. For example when I run "c" through I get "i" like I am suppose to. However when I set the password to "co" that is when I get the error.

Comment: After spending more time and going over it I realize where I went wrong. Thank you for helping

Comment: @Cloder glad it helped!